# В чем отличие REST API от HTTP?

Tags: веб-программирование, http, rest

Я так понял, что `REST API` предоставляет возможность взаимодействия на уровне методов `HTTP`, отправлять на сервер `GET, POST, PATCH, PUT`... запросы.

Но в чем тогда косвенное отличие?

Правильно ли я понимаю, что `REST API` - это мы просто взяли весь протокол `HTTP` для работы как базовую точку отсчета и поверх просто накинули пару архитектурных принципов как должны быть выстроены ссылки куда отправляться будут эти `HTTP` запросы?

Comment: HTTP это транспорт, REST это архитектура для API. Что у них общего? Ничего. Это как сравнивать тёплое и мягкое. REST пришел на замену SOAP, вот там отличия и ищите.

Comment: @aepot спасибо за ответ, то есть мое представление в конце вопроса правильное?

Comment: Сложно сказать, есть ли у вас понимание вообще, но в целом вы ничего в конце вопроса противоестественного не написали.

Comment: вопрос примерно аналогичен вопросу: чем отличается тепловоз от ж/д-колеи? (ответ: ну, по колее может ехать тепловоз, а может трамвай, а может электричка, а может вагонетка).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

как специалист по АПИ могу честно сказать что RESTом просто называют почти любое АПИ поверх HTTP как противовес SOAP, XML-RPC и JSON-RPC.

Исторически когда зарождался веб начали делать XML-RPC где есть один АПИ в который слали через POST команду в виде XML которая содержала имя метода\функции и параметры к ней. У Wordpress кстати ещё вроже сохранился XML-RPC АПИ через который можно создавать статьи. Можешь глянуть чтобы понять.

Потом корпораты добавили XML схему WSDL для описания функций и параметров и  так появился SOAP. Его прикол был в том что имея WSDL файл ты мог сгенерировать готовый клиент например на Java это был Axis.
Но сам по себе этот стандарт получился просто запредельно раздутый и сложный.
При этом всё равно все имплементировали его криво и постоянно куча проблем было. Чисто для примера если у тебя есть поле с датой то оно может форматироваться разными способами.
Сам же XML это очень сомнительный формат в котором например просто словаоь ключ:значение (map) передать нельзя и нужно делеать хитрую схемму.
Вообщем при слове SOAP у всех бывалых в глазах появляется страх и боль.
Тем не менее в банках и прочих "энтерпрайзах" до сих пор его используют.

Потом начали появлятся мобильные приложения и всякие Веб 2.0 сайты с AJAX. И для них нужно было что-то проще. Начали использовать JSON как формат сериализации вместо XML и просто слать POST запросы на сервер но уже не на единый АПИ эндпоинт а куда будет проще.
Почти все запросы были простыми CRUD: создать, получить, изменить да и удалить.

И тут Филдинг, один из создателей HTTP, выкатил предложение: а давайте будет переиспользовать HTTP методы и для создания использовать POST, для изменения PUT а для удаления DELETE. При этом будет достаточно только урла и не нужно слать команду в теле запроса.
Ну и это всем зашло потому что в теории выглядит очень гармонично. Но на практике же это адищще поскольку удаление почти никогда не надо делать а нужно просто помечать галочкой что удалено. Обновление иногда нужно делать хитрее, например менять пароль у пользователя это отдельная команда.

Тут нужно сделать важную оговорку: броузер сам никогда не шлёт PUT и DELETE. Только форма может засабмитить POST ну или даже GET.

Откуда тогда они взялись в HTTP спеке? А очень просто: изначально веб сделали в ЦЕРНе для просмотра документации не скачивая её всю. И в первом броузере даже можно было любую страницу редактировать и отсылать на сервер через PUT.
Но это быстро убрали и вместо этого задумали сделать полноценное расширение WebDAV для того чтобы несколько пользователей могли работать над одним документом и там сохранялась версия изменений. И вот пока делали вебдав решили часть его методов OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT впихнуть в основной HTTP стандарт. Но вообще там ещё больше методов всяких разных, например MKCOL для создания папки. Хорошо что про них никто не знает. А ещё лучше что люди не знают про UPnP где тоже есть свои методы типа NOTIFY.

Тут есть тонкий прикол: по факту АПИ твоего приложения "унаследует" HTTP а значит ты должен переиспользовать HTTP коды ошибок. И если пытешьс редактировать пользователя которого нет то нужно возвращать 404 ошибку.
Прикол в том если например ты просто неправильно сконфигурил адрес АПИ то ты всегда будешь получать 404 от самого вебсервера а не от твоего приложения.
И это отдельная боль.

Поэтому правильно будет не наследовать а делегировать и всегда отвечать с 200 OK  но в случае ошибки передавать её в теле ответа завёрнутую в JSON.

Потом спираль истории сделала новый виток и программистам понадобилось делать схемы апи и генерить клиенты как уже было с SOAP. Тогда придумали Swagger\OpenAPI который по сути тот же WSDL только уже на JSON.
И есть всякие там свагер генераторы которые тоже генерят клиенты с багами и несовместимые друг с другом.

Чуть позже намучившись с Рестом программисты взяли всё лучшее и отбросили то что не очень-то и надо типа схемы и придумали простой рабоче-крестьянский JSON-RPC. Это почти идеально для 95% нужд. Единственное что очень топорно файлы через него гонять ведь их нужно кодировать в base64 и запихивать в JSON поле. Если ты новичёк то бери его.

Там ещё в самом RESTе автор много ещё говорил про собственно архитектуру где не должно хранится состояния и другие приколы но это абсолютно никого уже не волнует потому что реальные системы всегда имеют свою собственную сущность и состояния с переходами.

Тем не менее если на собеседовании спросят то нужно сказать что это целый архитектурный стиль, а не хухры мухры!

Под конец добавлю что почти всегда в системе у тебя не просто запрос-ответ но ещё и события и подписка на них. Поэтому рано или поздно любой АПИ эволюционирует и начинает использовать постоянное подключение через WebSocket и модель событие-обработчик.
Но это уже другая история.